# Error in installing Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

hi i have installed the Java eclipse in my system according to the instructions given in http://developer.android.com. After the installation when i was to develop my new project the build target space seems to be empty. One of my friend instructed me to go to windows->Preferences->Android and in the SDK location i have entered the dir where sdk is been loaded (ie in my pc D:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows), but then also no change pls help me to clear my issue...

Comment: It would be easier if you specified the actual steps you have performed as it should work unless you have forgotten something. Have you used the SDK and AVD manager to actually download at least one version of the SDK platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Seems like you have installed SDK but Platform packages were not installed. Go to EClipse - > Window - > Android SDK and AVD Manager, check for Installed packages if that is empty go to available packages and install as per your wish

Answer (score 2):

Check if the location you've specified have the folder hierarchy as below?

Have you also clicked on the 'Apply' or 'Ok' button to reload the location after you're done specifying the location?
[image: SDK]